# GStreamer play multi-video mp4 file

Tags: gstreamer

On Windows, using gst 1.8.2 (from 1.6), I create mp4 files from multiple IP cameras streaming to a single mp4 file using the following gst-launch pipeline (I have reformatted my gst-launch commands to look better here, but they are single lines):

```
mp4mux name=m ! filesink location=file.mp4   
rtspsrc location="rtsp://x" latency=0 name=Camera1 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! tee name=t1 
   t1. ! queue ! m.video_1 
   t1. ! queue ! decodebin ! autovideosink name=video1   
rtspsrc location="rtsp://y" latency=0 name=Camera2 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! tee name=t2 
   t2. ! queue ! m.video_2 
   t2. ! queue ! decodebin ! autovideosink name=video2
```

I can play the resulting files with VLC media player, but I cannot play the file to using gstreamer. When I create a pipeline like

```
gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin name=u uri=file:/file.mp4 
   u.src_0 ! queue ! autovideosink 
   u.src_1 ! queue ! autovideosink
```

It never plays. While awaiting the video, I see

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Redistribute latency...
Redistribute latency...
```

And when I later hit ctrl-c, the response is

```
handling interrupt.
Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

A co-worker tries the same commands on his Mac and gets the same result.

I set the environment variable to produce the "DOT" pipeline graph files. They do not show the correct video format, width or height; I guess it never gets that far. I followed otopolsky's recipe and a single camera works, both with a command line example and my program.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

-reilly.

Comment: Updated to version 1.8.2 with no joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to add `-e` to the gst-launch at the beginning. I tested with simplified version of your pipe:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e mp4mux name=m ! filesink location=file.mp4 videotestsrc ! x264enc ! m.video_1 videotestsrc ! x264enc ! m.video_2
```

And play it like this. Your uri was wrong.. you need to provide full path or use filesrc (location can be relative) and decodebin instead..

This is proper pipe - not sure how to do the pwd in windows so use full path..

```
gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin name=u uri=file://`pwd`/file.mp4 ! video/x-raw ! queue ! videoconvert ! autovideosink u. ! video/x-raw ! queue ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

Comment: I tried the -e at the command line; no joy with my rtsp sources. Actually, I have written a C++ program, but I use gst_parse_launch for flexibility. I knew the uri was wrong; I was trying to limit the size of my post to show the relevant parts. Thanks for the suggestions, tho. Keep them coming!

Comment: @Reilly and what about playing my testing pipes - is it working?

Comment: I completely spaced and didn't run your example; I just tried to modify them for my use. Today I ran your example and it *does* work. I suspect you are onto something with the EoS. Let me try it again with the RTSP cameras and the command line.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer. I think there is a bug in either the Windows gstreamer port or else my pipeline. Less than half the time, with my rtsp source, I can create a file wherein gst can play the stream at src_1. but stream src_0 is always just black. Thanks for your help. I think EoS is the key to getting even this far.

Comment: I have two .mp4 file instead of `videotestsrc`. how can i combine(not append) that two mp4 into single mp4 file? Any inputs